# Populate MapLayers with Xaml-generated MapElements to use x:Bind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am populating the UWP MapControl with different kinds of MapElements - routes, pins, etc. It is essential for every element be updated when it's position changes.
Previously I was using MapItemsControl with x:Bind:

```
<maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Landmarks}">
  <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Datatype = "vm.Car">
          <Geopoint Location="x:Bind Location"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</maps:MapItemsControl>
```

But I had to change my approach so that I can display different kinds of MapElements. I was following [Guidance on MapLayers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#working-with-layers).

```
<maps:MapControl MapServiceToken="Your token" Layers="{x:Bind Landmarks}"/>
```

I populate the Landmarks collection in cs code and I can only create "normal" bindings between the MapElement and it's data-model. My goal is to visualise as many moving objects as possible, and performance of "normal" bindings is not good enough.

To improve performance I am currently update positions of the MapElements manually - it's a lot of extra code to maintain.

Is there any way to populate each MapLayer with MapElements using XAML, so I can create x:Bind bindings?

Comment: What "normal" binding you mean here? "populate each MapLayer with MapElements" what is this mean? I'm not sure what you want, could you please detail that?

Comment: I will re-write it tomorrow to make it clearer